# Finding the UUID of the device - UniqueDeviceID plugin

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, uuid

Trying to retrieve the Unique device ID of the Device .
Using the plugin - [UniqueDeviceID](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID)

When tring to run the following code

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
module.exports = {

get: function(success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, 'UniqueDeviceID', 'get', []);
}
```

};
`

I am getting the following error-
 "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined"

This is indeed defined in cordova.js
How do i fix this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using cordova's own plugin for that purpose ?
Usage : device.uuid
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html

Comment: isnt that depreciated for versions above 3 , which i am using in my project. the plugin used is an alternative for that only

Comment: As far as I'm aware of ,  the only deprecated thing is "device.name" which  is deprecated as of version 2.3.0. And you can use device.model instead. But about uuid, I have not seen any notification stating that that is deprecated as well. Plus I am using that in my project as well (version > 3) .   Could you please share the source that is claiming that's deprecated ?

Answer (score 0):

The get method needs to be called in the device.ready() of the application initialization.
Placing it elsewhere lead to the above mentioned error , worked fine for me .

Answer (score 0):

There is an in built function, for getting uuid:

```
var string = device.uuid;
```

> Full Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Kindly, visit this link:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used the UniqueDeviceID Plugin from this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid

Very simple and powerful. Tried to unistall and reinstall the app and still returned the same UUID. 
Two changes I had to make to make this plugin work for me:
1. The above link mentions to add a separate line to the config.xml file. I followed the same and I was unable to build my app. I removed the line and it works fine.
2. Also add a loop for the fail case just like the success case shown, otherwise there is a runtime error.

```
function fail(error) {
   console.log(error); };
```